# Error deploying change set

Tags: deployment, change-set

I am validating a change set containing multiple LWCs and Apex from Sandbox to Sandbox. Everything works in the sandbox originating the change.
Error when validating:

ORA-20070: Assertion Failed ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.ASSERT", line 11 ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.ASSERT", line 43 ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.CMANAGEABILITY", line 56 ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.CMANAGEABILITY", line 46 ORA-06512: at line 1 SQLException while executing plsql statement: {?=call cManageability.get_managed_state(?)}(null) Assertion Failed

Can't find anything online about that error.

Thanks

Comment: You've stumbled across a "dwarf", Sneezy. Those are issues that you'll likely need to work through the official Salesforce support channel to get resolved.

Comment: Thank you Derek

Answer (score 0):

After some review and isolation of components, we found a pattern: this specific error appears for me in Change Sets that contains a LWC that subscribe to a Lightning Message Channel. Maybe related with this: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003wQaQAI

There is a case open with Salesforce support for this.